# How to use email as username for Django registration

Tags: python, django, forms, django-registration

I am new to django and  creating registration form using django's UserRegistrationForm, which requires username and password . I want to use email instead of username. How I can do this?

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request,f'Account Created For {username} !')
            return redirect('starting-page')
    else:   
        form = UserRegisterForm()
    return render(request,'users/register.html',{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 0):

First step to use `email` as `username`  is to customize `User` model by extending `AbstractBaseUser`, something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, PermissionsMixin
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _ 

... 

class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)

    ...
    
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
```

Then, in your `settings.py`, you have to set your custom model user:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.CustomUser'
```

You can take a look at the [Django Registrations docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/custom-user.html#the-two-step-activation-workflow) to see any particular information on some of the required fields or methods depending on your workflow.

Comment: Can you tell me what underscore means in model fields?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the answer so you can see what it is the underscore. It isn't needed for your solution, but I copied from my codebase :-P